# Canvas and IMG size not the same when fetching the img asynchronously

Tags: css, ejs

I'm trying to draw an img of a cat and put a canvas of the same size on top if it.

If I give the ejs an img url directly, it works great. But if I fetch the img url from an api source and then renders the ejs, it doesn't work - the canvas size is 0.

This is how I fetch the img from the api:

```
let url = `https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?size=full`
    request(url, function (err, response, body) {
        if(err){
            console.log('Error!')
            // res.render('index', {catImageName: null, error: 'Error, please try again'});
        } else {
            let responsesArray = JSON.parse(body)
            let catJSON = responsesArray[0]

            if(catJSON !== null){
                let url = catJSON.url
                console.log(url)
                res.render('index', {catURL: url, error: null});
                // res.render('index', {catImageName: null, error: 'Error, please try again'});
            } else {
            }
        }
    });
```

This is how I do it without using the api:

```
let url = "https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/01-cat-wants-to-tell-you-laptop.jpg"
    res.render('index', {catURL: url, error: null});
```

This is the ejs part where I put the img and the canvas on top of it:

```
<div id="CatTab" class="tabcontent">
  <div class="imageContainer">
      <% if(catURL !== null){ %>
        <img id="catImage" class="catImage" src="<%= catURL %>"/>
        <canvas class="canvas" id='myCanvas'></canvas>
      <% } %>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the relevant part of the script:

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var catImage = document.getElementById("catImage");

 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 ctx.canvas.width = catImage.width;
 ctx.canvas.height = catImage.height;
```

This is the relevant css code:

```
.imageContainer {
  display: block;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0 auto;
  background-color: #b1f;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.catImage {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:1;
}

.canvas {
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border: 10px solid red;
  z-index:20;
}
```

I've put a red border around the canvas to see it, and this is how it looks when it doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: I got to set height on imageContainer

Comment: I forgot to add this part of the script - now its added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the script drawing the canvas in a function (i.e.: `drawCanvas() { /* code here */}`and run this function after the image has loaded, using `onload` on `<img>`:

```
<img id="catImage" class="catImage" src="<%= catURL %>" onload="drawCanvas()">
```

If you draw the canvas before the image loads, the width and height will be `0`. An alternative would be to size the `<img>` using CSS, so it has sizes even before it loads, but I wouldn't recommend it, as you probably want it to have different sizes depending on device screen width.